# Back button on custom navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, back-button, navigationbar

I am trying to develop an app with a navigation bar of custom size. (100px) In the navigation bar, I also want to include a back button. I have added both of them using the child view, but the back button is not working:

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menueButton.png"];
UIImage *backBtnImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menueButton.png"];

backBtn.exclusiveTouch = YES;
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, -40, 35, 32);
UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -40, 35 , 32)];
[backButtonView addSubview:backBtn];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButtonView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

My navigation bar size is 100 pixels tall, and when I use button position (0,0,35,32) it will work correctly.  But in this case, the button is being displayed much lower than intended. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(5, 9, 50, 30);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.btnBack];
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904579/making-custom-back-button-for-navigation-bar?rq=1) also.

Update:for back button

```
-(void)back
{

[self.btnBack removeFromSuperview];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: by using btnBack uiView two back buttons are displayed on all the screen but i want only one back button on few screens

Comment: found solution by replacing following code but now have a problem as when i visited screen and comeback to home screen the navigation bar button of the last visited screen is appearing on the home screen but i don`t have any bar button or custom button on the home screen

Comment: `UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menueButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(5, 15, 50, 32);
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:backBtn];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
`

Comment: thats Cool now ,  Thanks IPhone Programmtically for your support

Answer (score 0):

Try allocing backButtonView like this

```
UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35 , 32)];
```

Change : orgin of view to (0,0)

Edit

Try

```
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 32);
UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -40, 35 , 32)];
```

Comment: Lithu Thanks for your replying i have already tried it but still not work :(

Comment: backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 32);
 try this and make the other value as the same in question

Comment: i have tried both backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, -40, 35, 32);
UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35 , 32)]; and backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 32);
UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -40, 35 , 32)]; simultaniously but still not work