# How to Custom UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have design goal like picture in this: 
[image]

The problem is, `UIButton` `valign` cannot in center position, `UIButton` always relative to `UINavigationController` like this:
[image]

How to make `UIButton` valign in center of background image height not `UINavigationController` height?

Comment: Please update your question to properly show images instead of descriptions.

Comment: show the code you have used for that button

Comment: Are you using this button as a bar button or adding as a  subview??

Comment: You want to add button on navigation  bar or your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 self.btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(5, 9, 50, 30);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.btnBack];
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904579/making-custom-back-button-for-navigation-bar?rq=1) also.

Update:for back button

```
-(void)back
{

[self.btnBack removeFromSuperview];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create custom button and then add subview in navigation controller :-

```
UIButton * headerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
[headerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(headerButton1Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
headerButton.frame = CGRectMake(95, 1, 30,38 );
[headerButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[headerButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-icon-pressed"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:headerButton];
```

I hope this will help you.
Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good quick solution

```
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:20.0];   
myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

and hide your navigation bar by

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

then show your custom view

Comment: I try your code, its work my UIButton position is correct now. but I get another problem, my state position not same with UIButton position. How to fix this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is trick,

You can Hide navigationController using `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];`

and display custom view in top as you want.

Answer (score 0):

the prob you are facing because of the navigation bar height. Now there are two approaches. Either you can create a category for navigation bar and override the -(CGRect)sizethatFits method like given below:
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,100);
    return newSize;
}

Or you can hide the navigation bar like :
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
and put a header view and handle that.

Do what you would prefer to do..